# Undefined Object with Fetching Schema less Data from MongoDB using NodeJS and Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to do some models in mongoDB using mongoose as a schemaless during working saving data works fine but when i try to fetch the data there is problem

this is the Model Creation code :

```
const TemplateSchema = new Schema({
    any: {},
    blog: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'blogs'
    },
    user:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'users'
    },
    date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
},{ strict: false });
```

Saving Code :

```
let newTemplate = {
    tempbody: { name: 'Laith', age: 26 },
    blog: blog.id,
    user: req.session.userid,
}
//console.log(inputObject);
new Template(newTemplate).save()
    .then((template) => {
        res.redirect(`/blogs/posts/${req.params.blogid}`);
    });
```

Fetching Code :

```
Template.findOne({_id: req.params.templateid}).populate('blog').then(template =>{//To Fetch ObjectID for Blog from DB 
    if(template && template.blog.blogID == req.params.blogid) {
        console.log(template.tempbody);
        res.render('blogs/addPostTemplate', {
            template: template,
            blogid: req.params.blogid,
            templateid: req.params.templateid
        });
    } else {
        res.redirect(`/blogs/posts/${req.params.blogid}`);
    }
});
```

The result suppose to be :
The Object tempbody but it gives always undefined
and if i try to fetch template._id it works fine
and if i print template as full object it also gives the result

and sometimes gives : `(node:16840) [DEP0079] DeprecationWarning: Custom inspection function on Objects via .inspect() is deprecated`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `tempbody` is not a part of the schema so it will not be saved. Have you checked what gets saved to db after calling `new Template(newTemplate).save()` ? Also what do you expect `any: {},` to do? You would probably need in your schema something like `tempbody: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed }`

Comment: @Molda Thanks for the answer, actually it saves the tempbody object even if it's not there because i requested the schema strict: false , as per that it saves the tempbody object but when i try to fetch it, no respond my algorithm is that i have form input fields which is random as per the user wish.
User adds the input forms as much as he can and gives values so in the schema side i dont know what each user will form thats why i want to use schema less data inserts to the DB